# Output all array values to a cell

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm having a bit of trouble dealing with the output of array formulas in Excel, e.g.:

```
 {=IF(B3:D3>=4;"Something";"")}
```

What I want to achieve with this snippet is to print "Something" in the target cell if one value of the array is greater or equal to 4. If we assume our array is {1,1,4} the result should be {"","","Something"}, but Excel will only print the first value of the array resulting in a blank cell.

Is there an easy way to make this work?

Also, how do I compare an array against a "static" array? Something like:

```
Pseudocode
{=IF(B3:D3={1,1,1};"Every value is 1";"")}
```

Purpose being to determine if every value in B3:D3 is `1` then print something to the target cell.

Is it possible to enter an array/list like {1,1,1} directly into the formula?

I've Googled to no avail, could only find solutions where the "conditional" array was defined in an array somewhere on the sheet or just chaining the value checking with AND statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$3:$D$3,1)=COLUMNS($B$3:$D$3),"Every value is 1","")
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, that's pretty much exactly how I'm doing it right now - still would love to know if there's a way to check against a manual matrix/pattern like IF(B3:D3={8,5,8}) guess daisy chaining B3=8 AND C3=5, or defining a second array with your patters on the worksheet and compare against that is the only way to deal with things like that?

Answer (score 0):

First part can be done like this for a cell range:

```
=IF(MAX(B3:D3)>=4, "Something", "")
```

or for static array:

```
=IF(MAX({1,2,3,4})>=4, "Something", "")
```

Second part to check matching arrays must be done by pressing Ctrl_Shift_Enter when entering the formula:

```
IF(MIN((B3:D3={8,5,8})+0)>0, "Matches!!", "NOT matching")
```